# How to implement a faster condition checking function? python

Tags: python, c++, list, dictionary, cython

I have a small script that wants to extract some unique words based on several conditions and checking through the conditions is taking super long.

Possibly because it checks through a large dictionary and also it applies a stemmer to each token.

The conditions are:

- token not in chosen dictionary
- token length more than 1
- token is not in a fixed set of punctuation
- token is not not a pure digit
- token doesn't end with "'s"

**Is there any faster implementation of multiple condition checking?** Any solution that is python based is acceptable, even using subprocess or cython or calling c/c++ implementation.

Keep in mind that in reality, there are MORE conditions and the dictionary is up to 100,000 entries. I have done something like the following and even with `yield`, chaining up the multiple conditions is slow.

```
import string
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()

dictionary = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'water', 'eat', 'the', 'with', 'an', 'pie', 'full', 'of', 'water', 'at', 'lake', 'on', 'wednesday', 'plus', 'and', 'many', 'more', 'word']

text = "PEAR eats the Orange, with an Apple's MX2000 full of water - h20 - at Lake 0129 on wednesday."

def extract(txt, dic):
    for i in txt.split():
        _i = i.strip().strip(string.punctuation).lower()
        if _i not in dic and len(_i) > 1 and not _i.isdigit() \
        and porter.stem(_i) not in dictionary and not i.endswith("'s"): 
            yield _i

for i in extract(text, dictionary):
    print i
```

**[out]**

```
MX2000
h20
```

Comment: You won't fasten up the multiplicity of the conditions; combining them with `and` is the most useful way of doing it (in case they all need to be true).  But you might tweak your results at other points in the algorithm.  You could use `re.finditer()` instead of `split()` to iterate through the tokens in `txt`; this way you would not build a list of all tokens which you do not really need.

Comment: You could start by making `dictionary` an actually dictionary, not a list.

Comment: Or even a set.  `dictionary = { 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things off the top of my head:

1. Change dictionary to a `set` (as @Alfe suggested). Considering the long length of your data, this will definitely help the speed.
2. Since the comparisons will end as soon as some rule is false, you could rearrange the tests such that the fastest and/or most discriminative rule is run first. The best order is not directly clear to me in this case though. Experiment with it.

Comment: It's spelled "defin__i__tely"

Comment: @alvas "definately" is a common misspelling of "definitely" and one of my (and others') favourite pet peeves.

Comment: Always mix those up. Edited.